# Javascript - Format date to yyyy-mm-dd from unixtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

I need some help with converting unixtime to a specific format.  Here is what I am currently working with:

```
var date = "2014-05-01";
var indexPie = Date.parse(date);
```

I need indexPie in yyyy-mm-dd format.  What I do not understand is that when log

```
var newDate = new Date(indexPie);
```

The results is:

```
Wed Apr 30 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

when it should be:

```
Thur May 01 2014 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

Why is new Date(indexPie) resulting in Apr 30 and how do I get my correct format of yyyy-mm-dd?

Any suggestions would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Because `Wed Apr 30 2014 18:00:00 + 06 h` == `Thur May 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT`.

Comment: I see....sorry I mocked in some data

Comment: You get time in GMT-0600 timezone.

Comment: maybe it has something to do with your system time ... it works fine for me , here is the result `Thu May 01 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT (heure d’été))`

Comment: That is odd why I get Apr 30 2014 18:00:00?  I get that in JSFiddle as well

Comment: just add a time to your date

Comment: I also should have said that the parsed date (indexPie) is coming back from an API.  So I can't change the date or time before I receive the data.

Comment: Can you use an external library moment.js as it will make life easy for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the issue with the following:

```
var date = new Date(indexPie);
var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = date.getUTCDate();
var dateString = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting that the value in `date` variable: `"2014-05-01"` will be parsed as in local timezone, but actually it is parsed as in UTC.

You can convert the date from UTC to local timezone like this:

```
var newDate = new Date(indexPie + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```